# Can not bind data inside input field using angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two input filed and those are given below.

```
<input type="text" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" placeholder="short name" ng-model="dept_short_name" >
<input type="text" name="itemname" id="contactno" class="form-control" ng-model="loginname" readonly="readonly" value="{{dept_short_name}}" >
```

I need when user will type any text in first input field the second input field will update with same data simultaneously.Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" ng-model="dept_short_name" />
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" ng-model="dept_short_name"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

**It is simplest one task using angularjs.
Check the fiddle link.**

```
LINK:
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/19129/)

Answer (score 0):

In controller watch `dept_short_name` and change `loginname` as you want inside watch.